# Change top bar background color iOS with AIR for Mobile (AS3)

Tags: ios, mobile, user-interface, air, ios6

Is it possible to change the background color of the top bar in iOS 6 with AIR for Mobile or can this only be done in native Objective-C?

What I mean:

http://shurl.be/uLwt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a simple and easy solution for this.
Default the status bar style (`UIStatusBarStyle`) is set to `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque`.
Just change the value to `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent` and set the background color of the SWF to the color you want the status bar to have.

So what I've done is just this:
Added the settings below in the Application descriptor

```
  <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
  <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent</string>
```

And changed the SWF background color

```
    [SWF(backgroundColor="#ff6a00")]
```

Result:

[image: When I came here]
 VS 
[image: Now, (fixed)]

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this in objective-c:

You can change it from, Target Settings -> Summery -> tint of status bar

Or

you can change it back to black from, info.plist -> set value for status bar style as opaque black style.

Comment: Very nice, but I'm looking for a solution in AS3 (AIR for Mobile) :/.

Comment: Nvm, fixed it, see answer below :)!
Thanks anyway for the help!